# Dictionary for matchup in tournament and storing of dates with .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I am trying to create a quick lookup dictionary for same opponents being played with their dates.  The matchup has an Away Team and Home Team that play on a certain date.  Both teams have a Team ID.

I want to do a quick lookup on a matchup and see if they are playing say the next day against the same opponent.  An event director may have a minimum amount of days they want the same matchup to take place.  So if a matchup between two teams play 4/25 and the director wants a 1 day rest between the same matchup, then they can't be scheduled on 4/26, but 4/27 and above.  I need to create an array for quick lookups on this with thousands of matchups.

What is the best way to do this, a Dictionary of some sort in .NET? The key would be the Team ID of the Away and Home team and a list of DateTimes.

```
public class Team
{
   public int TeamId {get;set;}
}

public class Game
{
public Team Away {get;set;}
public Team Home {get;set;}
public DateTime Date {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Yes I dont care about who is Home or Away and if they are reversed, only that they are the same teams in the matchup.

Comment: If you have a function to do a a comparsion for DateTimeOffset, show me how I can validate if a team is playing in consective days with it, meaning a minimum game rester between opponents.  Why would I use DateTimeOffset anyway.

Comment: I can't follow you, do you just want to look up whether two teams have a match on a specific date?

Comment: @Fildor If I only look at the problem, it seems like it's just checking if a certain match exists. But from your conversation, it seems to have become a question of how to generate a schedule. So I am confused which one is the purpose.

Comment: I wouldn't even worry about the datetime stuff.  I just want a quick look up on the key (awayteamid and hometeamid) in some sort of dictionary that is fast then grab its contents which are the date list.

Comment: @Fildor: Recommending `DateTimeOffset` involves some assumptions which you are not in a position to make. We have no reason to assume a game's `Date` represents an actual point in time: by its name and by the OP's description, it could very well just be a calendar date. That whole discussion is a needless distraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a method like this to produce the keys for your dictionary or lookup:

```
(int, int) GetTeamPairKey(int teamId1, int teamId2) 
    => teamId1 < teamId2 ? (teamId1, teamId2) : (teamId2, teamId1);
```

This will always produce the same key for a given pair of teams, regardless of their order.

If you already have a list of games, make a Lookup like this:

```
var matchesByTeamPair = matchList.ToLookup(match => GetTeamPairKey(match.Home.TeamId, match.Away.TeamId));
```

If you order the games by their date first, it will be simple to scan through each entry in the Lookup to find whether there are games with consecutive dates, as the values stay in their original order.

If you need to maintain a collection, you can use a `Dictionary<(int, int), List<Game>>`, and call GetTeamPairKey on any Game to find what key (and therefore list) to add it to. Just make sure you create and add a new list any time there's not a matching team pair in the dictionary yet.

ValueTuples have a good performance profile, both for creation and for GetHashCode and Equals. More importantly, they'll do a better job of spreading out hash codes when you're using a bunch of consecutive integers for your team IDs, so your lookup doesn't have to scan through hundreds of games that ended up in the same bucket.